# how to create a time limit object in django

Tags: python, django

In this project I create some objects and I want to filter only objects that are created 120 seconds ago . I tried this Line :

```
Model.objects.filter(start_time__gte=Now() - timedelta(minutes=2) , user = request.user)
```

But It does not work for me . any other solution? (and django timezone is set on Asia/china)

Comment: you can use time series db and get the lastest one from there use your conditions on these

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, use [django.utils.timezone](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/i18n/timezones/).
Second, you have to set **minutes** argument for `datetime.timedelta` to negative value.

```
time_ago = django.utils.timezone.now() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=-2)
Model.objects.filter(start_time__gte=time_ago , user = request.user)
```